# Feasability of module or submodule for user picture migration

Tags: users, migrations

It seems like there would be a fairly large number of Drupal 6 websites with user pictures that will need to be migrated to Drupal 7 at some point and that the difficulty of migration might be keeping some sites from migrating.

There are various posts here and there about the code needed to migrate user photos but this may be daunting to some users. Would it be difficult to create a module that the user could configure with source and target directories using the configuration menu and that would then perform the migration, so that user could avoid getting into Drupal's internals?

It would also be nice if drush could be used for this migration, but the solution above would probably be accessible to more users.

I'm not a developer, so creating and maintaining a module seems to be more than I could commit to, but I'm wondering whether this would be easy for someone with more experience.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't realized that the dev versions of migrate and migrate_d2d now support migrating user pictures.

The UI asks for the location for files in the installation one is migrating from. In my case, pictures were stored under files/pictures but I only had to specify "...files". I don't know if it would work if user pictures are stored in a directory with a different name.

In any case, once I switched to the dev versions, it seemed to work.